# Applying run and stop button

Tags: jquery

How would i achieve the following:

1. when i click `run button`, it should hide itself and show `stop button`.
2. upon clicking the `run button`, it will execute the already coded statements, like still 
   being able to click a `previous` and `next button` while the `stop button` is still being shown
3. when i click the `stop button`, it should hide itself and show the `run button`.
4. it should exit or stop the statement intended to run by the `run button`

This is what i thought of at first, How can i do this right (Algo|Pseudocode|Simple presentation code)

```
  $('#run').click(function e(){
  //hide #run
  //show #stop

  //execute statements x
  //prev and next button must still be clickable here

  $('#stop').click(function e(){
  //hide #stop
  //show #run
  //go outside run to stop execute statements x
  });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the button behaviours you've described. The business of stopping a statement will depend on what they're doing and how. More information would be required to answer that.

```
$('#run').on('click', function(){
  $('#run').hide();
  $('#stop, #previous, #next').show();
  executeStatements();
});

$('#stop').on('click', function(){
  $('#run').show();
  $('#stop, #previous, #next').hide();
  // 
  // stopExecutingStatements();
  //
});
```

Comment: is it ok if ill send my actual codes inside the run button? the code which i wanted to execute when run is clicked and need to be stopped when stop button is clicked